# Text overflows colum in html 5 table

Tags: html, css, mobile

In the mobile layout I am facing the following problem:

[image]

The text of the second column overflows the vertical column separator line.
I tried putting some margin, but if I put some margin and the text is long, the final part of the text aligns on the left in the first column.

Can you provide me a hint as regards the CSS part?
[image]

[image]

without display block:

[image]

Comment: Provide the code too as that will make it easy for us to help :D

Comment: @PradyumnaPasumarty I edited my answer with the screenshots of the css used

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `display: block` on `td` table cells - this will destory the table structure and its automatic layout. Just erase that to reset it to the default `display: table-cell`

Comment: I tried with display table- cell but it shows staggered rows. I uploaded the picture showing the consequent result.

Comment: That looks like each row is an individual table. You should try to put them all in *one* table, with those rows really being only `tr`s, and the `table` tag only at the top and bottom.